# Create an RPM to distribute a custom SELinux policy

Tags: centos, rpm, selinux

I have created two custom SELinux Policy modules to allow rsyslog to parse audit.log.

Can I create an RPM of these two policies to distribute to 300+ clients? Is there a better way to go about this?

The clients are CentOS 5.10 machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CentOS ships their policies in rpms, so that's not a bad idea for you to do too. I doubt if there is any tool  specifically for distributing them.

However, installing this rpm on 300+ hosts is another matter and requires/would greatly benefit from some orchestration solution like mcollective, or spacewalk/satellite, or fabric etc.

I distribute my policies with puppet, but  either one of these things needs to be configured/enabled on your hosts as a prerequisite no matter how you choose to package your policies/settings, there is no getting around that without any solution to manage a large set of hosts in place, the job gets cumbresome.

If you got nothing in place already then maybe fabric is the tool for you to use.

Comment: Petter, my clients are utilizing SaltStack, so pushing out the RPM won't be any issue. I will take a look at the CentOS policies RPMs for an example.

Comment: ok good yes `rpm -qa "*policy*" ` any of those src rpms would give good insight i think.

Comment: I think I got it from here, hopefully. I will mark this as an answer.